# How to move post process to background

Tags: publish, wp-cron

We have a large wp install that is freezing up whenever an editor hits "publish". It seems that the culprit is the pinging processes that run, such as re-building the sitemap, etc.

Is it possible to move most of these processes to the background so that the site doesn't hold up until the processes are complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinging and similar is all done in the background already.

If you have a plugin rebuilding a sitemap or something, then consider using a different plugin which doesn't have the same rebuilding time issue.

Comment: That's what I thought, I just wanted to be sure. Thanks!